# How do I change a button image after a successful in app purchase with setNeedsDisplay?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I'm trying to learn how to use in-app purchase for iOS and I'm practicing trying to make a simple (it's not simple for me) app.

What I want to happen, is after pressing a button which has a background image on it, I want the in-app purchase flow to complete and on a successful purchase, I want the background image on that same button to change to a different image.

This is how I have attempted it:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

public var currentProductID: String! = ""
public var collectionIndex: String = ""

class PurchaseViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    @IBOutlet weak var movementsPurchaseButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func purchaseMovements(sender: UIButton) {
        for product in productArray {
            if product.productIdentifier == "something" {
                currentProductID = product.productIdentifier
                beginTransaction(SKPayment(product: product))
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                didBuyCategory(currentProductID)
                break
            case .Failed:
                ...
            case .Restored:
                ...
            default:
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    func didBuyCategory(collectionIndex: String) {
        defaults.setBool(true , forKey: collectionIndex)
        if (collectionIndex == "something") {
            movementsPurchaseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Checkbox-528.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            movementsPurchaseButton.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
        else if ...
        .
        .
    }

}
```

The in-app purchase works fine (I left out some functions to be brief here). The problem occurs when the code gets up to this line:
`movementsPurchaseButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Checkbox-528.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

The error is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

And I can see that the instance of the UIView that the app is trying to change the image of is all nil...

```
UIKit.UIViewController  UIViewController    
movementsImageView  UIView! nil None
movementsPurchaseButton UIButton!   nil None
```

I don't understand why it is nil, why it is a new instance of the button and not the original button, and what I need to do to access the original button. I just want to the background image to change on success, why is it so hard?

Comment: First: `didBuyCategory()` should be called before you finish the transaction. Second: Check if the image itself is loading "Checkbox-528.png" Third: How did you set the old background image in the first place?

Comment: Ok @Jad I switched the order of `didBuyCategory()` and `.finishTransaction(transaction)`. The original image I added in the storgyboard UI with the attribute inspector. The image itself also does load programatically, for instance if I load it in `viewDidLoad()` it's fine.

Comment: "The original image I added in the storgyboard UI" did you use the image or the background image?

Comment: try to wrap setImage or setbackgroundImage with `DispatchQueue.main.async {//Your setImage or setBackgroundImage }`

Comment: @Jad I set the background image in both the storyboard editor and in the code. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Jad unfortunately wrapping it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }` didn't work

Comment: If I put `setBackgroundImage` code into the `purchaseMovements` button function, then the image changes as soon as I press the button. It just doesn't work from the `didBuyCategory` function...